# Automatically Assign Values To $fillable attribute (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to Sync data from a Localhost database to a Live one using Laravel 4. Everything works fine except for a table where columns' are dynamic. So in my Model I did something like:

```
<?php
class myModel extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $connection = 'live';
    protected $table = "myLiveTable";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setFillable();
    }
    public function setFillable()
    {
        $fields = someSQLHandler::getColumns('myLocalTable');

        $this->fillable = $fields;
    }
}
```

in order to prevent typing the fields in `$fillable` manually as it is impossible!

Is there any way to make it automatically assigned or at least prevent the Mass Assignment error even if I know it's a bad practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a black-list instead of a white-list:

```
protected $guarded = array('id', 'random_column');
```

And remove the `$fillable` completely.