# How to make dynamic form fields in laravel fillable

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am working with Laravel 5 .

The problem is that i have to add fields into a form dynamically using jquery and then submit the form.

Laravel has a requirement that all form variables need to be made fillable in the Model.
So the issue is how can i make this dynamic fields fillable ? Can anyone help me with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `$guarded` instead of `$fillable`. It's basically the opposite of `$fillable`: instead of saying 'You can only fill in these fields', `guarded` says 'You can fill in any field *but* these'.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641854/automatically-assign-values-to-fillable-attribute-laravel-4) gives an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use construction like:

```
Model::unguard();
$data = $request->except(['_token']);
$model = Model::create($data);
Model::reguard();
```

But beware of modificated requests - user can send value to field, which you don't want to set. More about guarding you can read in laravel  docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment